# Django assign user to group during registration based on choice in another field

Tags: django

I would like to automatically assign users to a group based on their choice in another field in the user registration field. I am new to Django and I am not sure of the best way to achieve this.

I want to assign the group based on the choice of the "business_location_county" field in the model. In simple terms the group should be the group id where the group "forum_id" equals the id of the business_location_county choice. The group "forum_id" is a custom column added to the Group model.

The models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from machina.core.db.models import get_model
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

Forum = get_model("forum", "Forum")

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    business_location_state = models.ForeignKey(Forum, null=True,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, limit_choices_to={"lft":1})
    business_location_county = models.ForeignKey(Forum, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='county', limit_choices_to=(~Q(lft__in = (1,2))))


Group.add_to_class('forum_id', models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True))
```

views.py:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django.shortcuts import render
from machina.core.db.models import get_model
from django.db.models import Q

Forum = get_model("forum", "Forum")


class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'

def load_counties(request):
    parent_id = request.GET.get('business_location_state')
    counties = Forum.objects.filter(parent_id=parent_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'hr/county_dropdown_list_options.html', {'counties': counties})
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('username', 'email', 'age', 'business_location_state', 'business_location_county')

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['business_location_county'].queryset = CustomUser.objects.none()




class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'age','business_location_state', 'business_location_county')
```

I am attempting to use post_save signal to accomplish this. However before I tackle trying to save the user to the group, I need to figure out how to get the Group id where business_location_state id is equal to Group forum_id.

I tried (unsuccessfully) adding this to the models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import (
    post_save
)

def user_addgroup_handler(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    g = Group.objects.get(id, limit_choices_to=(Q(forum_id__in = CustomUser.business_location_county)))
    print (g)


post_save.connect(user_addgroup_handler, sender=CustomUser)
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With help from an expert the following works:

```
def user_addgroup_handler(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    # g = Group.objects.get(id, limit_choices_to=(Q(forum_id__in = CustomUser.business_location_county)))
    # group = Group.objects.get(name=instance.business_location_county.name)

    # for g in CustomUser.objects.all():
    #     print(g.business_location_county_id)

    if created:
        # Get or create group
        new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(
            name=instance.business_location_county.name, forum_id=instance.business_location_county.id)

        # add new group to user
        instance.groups.add(new_group)


post_save.connect(user_addgroup_handler, sender=CustomUser)
```